# Start a gnome-terminal at a certain position, certain size and font size

Tags: linux, terminal, fonts, gnome

Before I start I have looked around and cannot find a solution to my problem. You may think this is similar to other questions but please read all the way through.

So what I want to do is write a little script that will start a gnome-terminal at a certain position and a certain width and height which I know how to do but what I don't know is how can I zoom in, by that I mean make the text font larger without increasing the size of the window.

I have a little console program and the problem is that it is to small, I want to launch it with a bigger font size so everything looks bigger instead of it just filling the corner of a terminal or instead of the terminal being really little. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`gnome-terminal --help-all` is your friend. You can try `gnome-terminal --geometry=80x10+x+y --zoom=2 --command="your program"`. Where `zoom=1.0` is the normal size and x & y specify position.